# nginx location directive is prepended to url path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm setting up an alias within a location directive "/folder". The alias points to "/my/alias/path".

When I navigate to a URL within the location, e.g. "mydomain.com/folder/destination", the directive name is being prepended to the request, which resolves to 
"/my/alias/path/folder/destination" (undesired) instead of 
"/my/alias/path/destination" (desired).

I'm probably missing something or don't quite understand how location and aliases work.

I've tried adding forward slashes to the location directive as well as the alias, but that doesn't work either.

Here's my location directive:

```
location ^~ /folder {
    alias /my/alias/path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(bin|SQL)/ {
         deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         allow all;
    }
}
```

Here's what I see in my error.log

```
/my/alias/path/folder/destination/index.php (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error relates to a `.php` file, and is probably generated by php-fpm because the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is set incorrectly.

Inside `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` you are probably setting `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`, which is incompatible with the `alias` directive. Use `$request_filename` instead.

For example:

```
location ^~ /folder {
    alias /my/alias/path;

    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

By placing the `fastcgi_param` statement after the `include` statement, the new value will silently overwrite the incorrect value.